# DirectX Present Parameters Windowed=false not working

Tags: c++, directx, 2d-games

I am trying to make a game.  I am using directx 9 to do so and I have some issues trying to go into full screen mode.  I made a function that initalized all of the Present Parameters .  Everything is fine except when I make windowed = false (ie i set fullscreen to true).

here is my present parameters variable: `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;`

Here is the code for the d3dpp variable.  Most if not all of this code comes from a book called Programming 2d Games by charles kelley.

```
void Graphics::initD3Dpp()
{
try {
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));              

    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = width;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = height;
    if (fullscreen)                                  
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;  
    else
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;   
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = mainhwnd;
    d3dpp.Windowed = (!fullscreen); //THIS LINE RIGHT HERE IS THE ISSUE
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
}
catch (...)
{
    throw(GameError(gameErrorNS::FATAL_ERROR,
        "Error initializing D3D presentation parameters"));

}

}
```

I do not see why .windowed does not work for me.  Please ask me if you need more context.

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? What you see and what you expected to see?

Comment: What width & height did you pick? Remember it has to be a supported display mode.

Comment: it doesnt work because when I create my directx device, it is a null pointer and my program crashes.  when i use fullscreen but when there is no fullscreen, the directx device is created.

Comment: I chose 600x480 (rather my book told me to use 600x480).

Comment: Show your `CreateDevice` call. What `HRESULT` do you have from `CreateDevice`? And put all additional data to question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you suggest that you are using 600x480. It's highly doubtful that this is a supported resolution on your system, more likely, you meant to be using 6**4**0x480. As far as I know, this resolution is supported by essentially every D3D9 driver.

However, hardcoding the resolution is not a robust solution, it's far more practical to follow the advice stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172588(v=vs.85).aspx) for `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS`, and use the [`EnumAdapterModes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174314(v=vs.85).aspx) function, to get a list of valid resolutions and display formats for your device.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my code.  But, it still does not work and is going to take a long time to fix.  I just ditched my code and am now using the code that my book supplied to me.